# Is there a way to marshal different response codes in flask_restx?

Tags: flask, flask-restx

With:

```
@api.marshal_with(response_model, code=200)
```

We can marshal a response with a predefined response model `response_model` and a status code.

My question is let's say we run a validation on the request and we want to throw a 400 error.

Is it possible to marshal the same method with a different model and a different code with:

```
@api.marshal_with(response_model_2, code=400)
```

Comment: if you will just do 
@api.marshal_with(response_model)

and return {}, 200 or return {}, 400

the status code accordingly changes